# Realizar una consulta de todos los elementos de un ListBox C# form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

en un formulario tengo dos ListBox el primero **lbxIncorrectos** que es donde se almacenan los ids que tienen una incidencia ya registrada y otro **LbxNombresSeleccionados** que seria el que le mostraria al usuario con los nombres de el personal en lugar de los ids, lo realice de la siguiente manera;

**Codigo**

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in lbxIncorrectos.Items)
            {
                ids.Add(item.ToString()) ;
            }
            Access.ExecQuery($"SELECT NOMBRE from PERSONAL_LABORAL where ID_PERSONAL_LABORAL in ({string.Join(" , " , ids)})");
            LbxNombresSeleccionados.DataSource = Access.DBDT;
            LbxNombresSeleccionados.DisplayMember = "NOMBRE";
```

Me funciona a medias ya que en el **lbxIncorrectos** por poner un ejemplo, si se encuentran 2 elementos (1, 2) al pasar los datos al **LbxNombresSeleccionados** solo me muestra el nombre del (1) y no del (2) y así sucesivamente es decir si tengo 8 elementos (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) solo pasa los de (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), dejando siempre el ultimo id sin consultar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo dudas de por que no esta jalando todos los items del ListBox ya que por eso trate de usar un *Foreach* ojala me pudieran orientar como resolver  ese detalle o si hay alguna otra forma de obtenerlo, saludos

Comment: te fijaste como queda armado tu string para la consulta?

Comment: Así es y esta correcto, lo que si cheque es que el evento que dispara los ids correctos e incorrectos era lo que me estaba ocasionando que no me cargara los ids  en la consulta, estaba antes de que comenzara a cargar los ids incorrectos, lo puse después y ya me carga correctamente todos los elementos, en si el código estaba bien, el error fue la asignación que disparaba el evento.